# Can weak-learner be defined in the case of regression problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, boosting, definition, pac-learning

weak-learner is often defined relating to PAC learning.
However, to the extent I know, I have never seen the definition of weak-learner when regression.

That is, the definition of weak-learner on wikipedia is as following.
"A weak learner is defined to be a classifier that is only slightly correlated with the true classification", which is defined only when $f$ is classifier.

Is this definition extended to regression case?

Answer (score 1):

According to Bishop in [*Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/pattern-recognition-machine-learning/):

> Boosting can give good results even if the base classifiers have a performance that is only slightly better than random, and hence sometimes the base classifiers are known as *weak learners*.

See also the [What is meant by 'weak learner'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82049/what-is-meant-by-weak-learner) thread.

You can replace “classifier” with “algorithm” or “regressor” and the definitions would not change their meaning. In fact, people often use classifiers as a general case in machine learning literature and generalize from it to regression, or sometimes loosely use “classifier” to mean machine learning algorithm in general. This is also what Bishop does:

> Boosting is a powerful technique for combining multiple ‘base’ classiﬁers to produce
> a form of committee whose performance can be signiﬁcantly better than that of any
> of the base classiﬁers. [...] Originally designed for solving classiﬁcation
> problems, boosting can also be extended to regression [...]

What we use as weak learners for regression are often regression trees vs classification trees for classification.

Answer (score 0):

> weak-learner is often defined relating to PAC learning.

PAC learning only consider binary classification to build a learning theory. But it can be applied to any supervised learning setting.

> Is this definition extended to regression case?

Naively, we can extent this definition to regression models. Since, by weak-learning we imply poorly performing model but slightly better than random guess. A regression model can be considered a weak-learner, with the following conditions.

- Consider percentage-error type measure of performance.
- 50% recent-error could be considered as a random-guess learner.
- Weak-learner would give slightly higher percentage error than a random-guess.